# Syntax error in Python 3.6 using ,end""

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

My code reads:

```
print("Please key in a word: ",end" ")
first=input()
print("And now key in another: ",end" ")
second=input()
print("You have typed: "+first+" "+second)
```

but I get the result "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and the ^ pointing to the second " following end. I am using Python 3.6, so the end notation should be correct. I have tried with and without a space between the "" after end. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You need to assign the value: `end=" "`

Answer (score 2):

Keywords need to be assigned their values using `=`:

```
print("Please key in a word: ", end=" ")
first = input()
```

However, a better way would be to use `input()` directly:

```
first = input("Please key in a word: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the = sign between end and " ":

```
print("Please key in a word: ",end=" ")
first=input()
print("And now key in another: ",end=" ")
second=input()
print("You have typed: "+first+" "+second)
```